# Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::fetch_array()

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

in this code i get the error: Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::fetch_array()

What is the problem?

```
$search= "player";

($sql = $db->prepare('select job from jobs where job like ?'));

$sql->bind_param('s', $search);
$sql->execute();
$sql->bind_result($search);

$data = array();

while ($sql->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $data[] = array(
            'label' => $row['job']  
    );
    echo json_encode($data);

}

$sql -> close();
$db -> close();
```

thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using prepared statements there is no `fetch_array()`. Use `mysqli_stmt::fetch()` instead or to fetch multiple records use `mysqli_result::fetch_all()`

Check the manual: [mysqli_stmt::fetch()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php) or [mysqli_result::fetch_all()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php)