# PHP and Mysqli code error message

Tags: php, mysqli

I have this PHP code which another user on the site was helpful enough to give to me. It is trying to match entries in a database to what the user supplied in a form, and echoing out the picture(s) that match those specifications.

(I define my database info in the first 4 lines, but this site doesn't want to write them out)

```
// Errors
$error = array();
if (!isset($_POST['submit']))
    $error[] = "The form was not set.<br />";

// Here we check if each of the variable are set and have content
if (!isset($_POST['gender']) || strlen($_POST['gender']) == 0)
    $error[] = "You must fill the gender field.<br />";

if (!isset($_POST['hair']) || strlen($_POST['hair']) == 0)
    $error[] = "You must fill the hair field.<br />";

if (!isset($_POST['height']) || strlen($_POST['height']) == 0)
    $error[] = "You must fill the height field.<br />";

if (!isset($_POST['body']) || strlen($_POST['body']) == 0)
    $error[] = "You must fill the body field.<br />";

if (empty($error))
{
    $con = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name);
    if ($con->connect_error)
        die('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') '. mysqli_connect_error());

    // Here we prepare your query and make sure it is alright
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE gender=? AND hair=? AND height=? AND body=?";
    if (!$stmt = $con->prepare($sql))
        die('Query failed: (' . $con->errno . ') ' . $con->error);

    // Here we define the field types with 'ssss' which means string, string, string
    // and also set the fields values
    if (!$stmt->bind_param('ssss', $_POST['gender'], $_POST['hair'], $_POST['height'], $_POST['body']))
        die('Binding parameters failed: (' . $stmt->errno . ') ' . $stmt->error);

    // Now we finally execute the data to update it to the database
    // and if it fails we will know
    if (!$stmt->execute())
        die('Execute failed: (' . $stmt->errno . ') ' . $stmt->error);

    // Now we read the data
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch_object())
    {
        $pic = $row->picture;
        echo $row->picture, "\n";
    }
    $stmt->close();
    $con->close();
}
else
{
    echo "Following error occurred:<br />";
    foreach ($error as $value)
    {
        echo $value;
    }
}
?>
```

I am getting this error message on line 48

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::fetch_object() in /home/content/...
```

which is this line of code:

```
// Now we read the data
while ($row = $stmt->fetch_object())
```

Comment: MySQLi prepared statements cannot call `fetch_object()` as can be done with `query()`. You must `bind_result()` into variables, then call `fetch()` to populate those variables. This is probably the chief reason PDO is generally more popular.  Fetching is a big hassle with MySQLi prepared statements.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli\_stmt::fetch\_array()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5656676/fatal-error-call-to-undefined-method-mysqli-stmtfetch-array)

Comment: Look over the examples in the [MySQLi `prepare()` docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) to see how fetching is handled.

Answer (score 0):

You can't fetch the results from a `mysqli_stmt` object directly.  First use `get_result` to get a `mysqli_result` object, then use `fetch_object` on that:

```
$result = $stmt->get_result();
while ($row = $result->fetch_object())
```

Note that that only works if you have mysqlnd installed; if not, see the `bind_result` and `fetch` methods for a less convenient (but more compatible) approach.

Comment: Note that [`get_result()` is not available on all systems](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.get-result.php) as it depends on the newer mysqlnd driver.

Comment: Thanks to Robadob for his edit notifying me that there is a `fetch_object` method; unfortunately I clobbered his edit with my edit.