# Error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::fetch_object()

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to get this select statement to work however when I run the page I am returned with this error:  `Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::fetch_object()`.

This is my statement:

```
<?php 
$id = escape($_GET['id']);
$records = array();
$results = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `bookings` WHERE id = ?");
$results->bind_param('i', $id);
 if ($results->execute()) {
while ($row = $results->fetch_object()) {
    $records[] = $row;
}
$results->free();
}
?>
```

Then I would like to loop through below like this:

```
<?php foreach ($records as $data) {... ?>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Use PDO if you want to fetch objects. mysqli does not support it

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5656676/fatal-error-call-to-undefined-method-mysqli-stmtfetch-array