# Why is my mysqli_fetch_assoc not grabbing the row info so I can insert details into my table?

Tags: php, mysqli

First off, I know about sql injection and that my code is not foolproof, prone to injection etc. Will be working on that next.

Now : from my Android app to my PHP file I submit a JSON array of phone numbers like :

```
[{"phone_number":"+12345678"},
 {"phone_number":"+23456789"},
 {"phone_number":"34567890"},
 {"phone_number":"45678901"} 
 etc... etc...
```

These are contacts in my app user's phone. If these contacts are people who are also users of my app then I want to insert those numbers into my `contacts` table.

But I can't get it to work. `mysqli_fetch_assoc` isn't working correctly. I don't know why.

In my `contacts` table I have 3 columns - an `auto increment`, `user_id` and `contact_id`. The first two values are inserted correctly but the `contact_id` is always put in as '0', which is wrong.

Here is my code :

```
require('dbConnect.php');

//this is me, +567890123, my user_id in the user table
$user_id = '20';

//post all contacts in my phone as a JSON array
$json  = $_POST['phonenumber'];
$array = json_decode($json);

foreach ($array as $value) {
    $phonenumber = $value->phone_number;

    $sql      = "SELECT username FROM user WHERE username = '$phonenumber'";
    $result   = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    $num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    if ($num_rows > 0) {
        echo "phonenumber is " . $phonenumber . "<br>";

        // we want to put $phonenumber in the contacts table, as one of +567890123 contacts
        // In the user table get the associated rows of $phonenumber
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        // get the associated user_id in that row, that's what we want to put into the contacts table
            $contact_id                   = $row['user_id'];
            $insert_into_contacts_command = "INSERT INTO contacts VALUES(NULL, '$user_id','$contact_id')";
            $insert_into_contacts_table   = mysqli_query($con, $insert_into_contacts_command);
        }

    } //if +353864677745 is NOT in the user table...
    else {

        echo 'not a match.';
    }
}
```

Comment: And "does not work" means what _exactly_? Remember that we cannot look over your shoulder. You need to tell us exactly what happens, what you see, what your error log file contains.

Comment: Apart from that please note that your code is wide open to sql injection attacks. You should learn about the benefits of using "prepared statements" in combination with "parameter binding" to make your code more robust in that detail.

Comment: please use `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` on top of your page and let us know what PHP returns as error

Comment: `Will be working on that next.` -> if you don't have time to do it properly AND **safely** from the very beginning, you won't find time later ! unless you have to re-create it all from scratch because someone deleted all of your data... **DO or DO NOT ! there is no try**

Comment: @OldPadawan Sorry, but some people need to learn to walk before they can run.

Comment: But usually they learn pretty fast to place their feet on the ground for safety reasons _before_ climbing trees :-) Basic safety aspects should be learned _right away_, since all examples demonstrate them and things are easier that way anyhow. You will only get annoyed and frustrated with strange issues due to missing escaping of values anyway if you don't use parameter binding.

Comment: @CHarris : you're right, and when you teach someone how to walk, you help him not to fall, you don't encourage her/him to fall.. you should **really** consider using [PPS : Prepared Parameterized Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) from now on. It's not hard to learn, and make code so much [ anything positive you want to add here ] (EDIT: I'm no pro coder at all, no code tycoon, just code lover, and it took me less than a day to make some nice code from outdated one I had)

Comment: Think about it like this: if you do it the right way first, you don't have to go back and do the work twice. Plus, we're only human, things are easily forgotten. So I honestly can't see s reason for not doing prepared statements right away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query selects the column `username`, not `userid`.

You haven't posted anything about the table `user`, so it's hard to suggest a new query, but I guess it's the following:

```
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT userid FROM user WHERE username = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $phonenumber);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($userid);

while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    // Work with $userid
}
```

You'll note that this uses a prepared statement with a bound parameter. That way, your code is not prone to SQL injections.

Comment: Well spotted! However this repeats the major slap that makes the code vulnerable which is _not_ a good thing to do in an answer. _At least_ you should clearly point out that issue. Better would be to provide an example less questionable.

Comment: @arkascha No disrespect, but regardless of whether my code is vulnerable or not it is valid PHP code which presents a problem and asks for an answer, which is the purpose of stackoverflow - people have code questions, people answer them. Maybe another site where another layer has to be added on - the question must be code based AND the code must be completey safe in order to merit an answer, I don't know.

Comment: @CHarris: No, arkascha mentions this to me, not to you, and the remark is correct. I want to write good code, after all.

Comment: @Pharaoh Does my $insert_into_contacts_command need to be secured or is that ok?

Comment: Everything needs to be secured :) Everything that touches input from outside your code (like `$_POST`) needs to be waterproof, of course, but even code that does not do this can make you vulnerable. Just secure everything - you'll write the queries faster than you'll need to think about whether to secure this specific query. Just do it.

Comment: @Pharaoh I believe fetch_array doesn't work with prepared statements ? http://stackoverflow.com/a/5656704/307157

Answer (score 2):

```
$contact_id = $row['user_id'];
```

Here `$contact_id` will be `null`, because you are trying to access not existing field `$row['user_id']` of the `$row` .

Actually there is only one field `username` in your results set, as you specified:

```
$sql = "SELECT username FROM user WHERE username = '$phonenumber'";
```

Try to change your query to this:

```
$sql = "SELECT user_id, username FROM user WHERE username = '$phonenumber'";
```