# Getting an undefined error when trying to print results from database

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm learning how to do database coding on the php side. I've managed to successfully insert information into my database but I am having trouble getting from it. How can I print the data out? Nothing fancy, I would like to know the raw way we get the data out, so something like `print_r`. Here is my code:

```
<?php

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $dBUsername, $dbPassword, $dbName);
$stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
$result = fetch_ids_outs($stmt, $id);

function fetch_ids_outs($stmt, $id) {

    $userID = search_for_user($stmt, $id);
    if ($userID == false) return "User not in Database";

    // Otherwise get the data
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id = ?";
    if(!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
        return false;
    } else {
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "i", $userID);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
        mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);
        while($row = $stmt->fetch_array()) {
          echo $row['name'];
          echo "<br/>";
        }
    }
}
```

---

Error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::fetch_array() in C:\xampp\htdocs\outfit\save_outfit.test\test.php:77 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\outfit\save_outfit.test\test.php(88): fetch_cids_outs(Object(mysqli_stmt), 151172293) #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\outfit\save_outfit.test\test.php on line 77
```

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5656676/fatal-error-call-to-undefined-method-mysqli-stmtfetch-array

Comment: @sureshbambhaniya I am trying to make it so it is as secure as possible. The examples I see don't mention any security, so I am afraid to use it. And I have;t used this new way to connect to the database, so I am more affraid of using it

Comment: `stmt` is `mysqli_statement` object. `fetch_array` is used with `mysqli_result` object.

Comment: @u_mulder isn't that this mysqli_stmt_store_result

Comment: Here is a good article that has lots of good case uses.  This should answer alot of your questions.  https://websitebeaver.com/prepared-statements-in-php-mysqli-to-prevent-sql-injection

Comment: @Joseph_J I saw in a tutorial I watch, that if I do a statement prepare (like I am doing in my code above), people cannot sql inject me. Is this correct?

Comment: Using parameterized queries are safe from sql injection.

Comment: There are proper examples on how to do this in the link I give you earlier.

Comment: @Joseph_J So what I did is good (like the first bit, not the printing part of course).

Comment: @Joseph_J Because I thought all you have to do to escape sql inject is just `mysql_real_escape_string()` your strings or use the `?`

Comment: Seriously, read that article I linked you to.  It literally teaches you how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean `get_result()`, not `store_result()`.

Here's the example:

```
function fetch_ids_outs($stmt, $id) {

    $userID = search_for_user($stmt, $id);
    if ($userID == false) return "User not in Database";

    // Otherwise get the data
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id = ?";
    if(!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
        return false;
    } else {
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "i", $userID);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
        $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt); // get result
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { // fetch by associative index
          echo $row['name'];
          echo "<br/>";
        }
    }
}
```